# How to display mouse coordinates in a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel

```
    JLabel x_label = new JLabel("");
    x_label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    x_label.addMouseListener(simple_widget);
    x_label.setText(simple_widget.stringInfo);
    info_panel.add(x_label);
```

I am having trouble displaying the x,y coordinates of the mouse on a JLabel. Above is my label and below is the mouse widget. x_label.setText(simple_widget.stringInfo); does not seem to work in displaying the coordinates.

```
private FrameView frame_view;
public String stringInfo;


public SimpleFrameViewWidget(Frame f) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame_view = new FrameView(f);
    frame_view.addMouseListener(this);
    add(frame_view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel title_label = new JLabel(f.getTitle());
    add(title_label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();

    String stringInfo = "X: " + x + "Y: " + y;
}
```

Comment: When the mouse is clicked you make a new String, but never assign it to the label's text.

Answer (score 0):

You made a `String` called stringInfo that contains what you want, but you never made any UI components display it.

After you create stringInfo, try having one of your `JLabel`s display it like:

```
someJLabelIMade.setText(stringInfo);
```

You also have two stringInfo's, a local variable and a public instance variable, given what you wish to do right now you don't need the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

This method

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
int x = e.getX();
int y = e.getY();

String stringInfo = "X: " + x + "Y: " + y;
}
```

Should be like this

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
int x = e.getX();
int y = e.getY();

stringInfo = "X: " + x + "Y: " + y;
}
```

You are redeclaring stringInfo inside a method so the original stringInfo is null.
If this doesn't solve your problem can you post full code please?